# Angular translate - different asynchronous files for same language?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

Angular translate does a nice job to support multiple languages to load asynchronously. It does not however support loading different files for the same language, with the differentiation being region.

```
$translateProvider
 .determinePreferredLanguage( )
 .registerAvailableLanguageKeys( [ 'en', 'de' ], {
    en_us: 'us',
    en_uk: 'uk',
    de_de: 'de'
 })
 .useStaticFilesLoader( {
    prefix: '/localization/i18n/',
    suffix: '.json'
 })
```

I am trying to get this to work using fallbacks and language negotiation, but any other solution would be helpful.

A particularly hacky way I want to avoid is to create a dummy language to 'uk'. This following code works,

```
$translateProvider
 .determinePreferredLanguage( )
 .registerAvailableLanguageKeys( [ 'en', 'uk', 'de' ], {
    us: 'us',
    uk: 'uk',
    de: 'de'
 })
 .useStaticFilesLoader( {
    prefix: '/localization/i18n/',
    suffix: '.json'
 })
```

This changes a lot of other places in the app where en_uk is required (region specific API calls).

Answer (score 0):

Would setting the fallback language to en and your dummy en_uk (should really be en_gb) only needs to override specific translations not work ?

I am missing something or is it something like https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/563 that you are experiencing

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the way `determinePreferredLanguage` always fetched browser language as en_US, so the App was ending up calling en.json.

I ended up having to use `$translate.use( langKey )` in my controller where `langKey` was the language based on my required region.